# Migrate Hypersonic DB to MySQL/MariaDB

Tags: sql, migration, mariadb, hsqldb

I run an OpenKM instance and I'm running out of HDD, so I want to migrate to a MariaDB Cluster.

Is there any way to migrate a 30Gb+ Hypersonic DB to MariaDB?

Comment: Will you have more space on the MariaDB nodes?  Are you specifically going to use Clustering, or will it be a single node?  Does Hypersonic take more (or less) space for storing data than MySQL/MariaDB?  Does Hypersonic have an "export" command/tool?

Comment: It's not just a matter of space, because as a VM I can expand its HDD. I will be more comfortable with a MariaDB database that I can manage it better. In the other hand, I only found a windows migration tool but I don't know if it will capable to migrate a 30Gb+ file-database.

Comment: "A migration tool" would be rather lame if it could not handle 30GB.  What took?

Answer (score 0):

The latest MySQL Workbench tool comes with a migration feature, take a look here https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/migrate/